# Custom increment stepper not showing incremented value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I made a custom increment stepper in js, the problem is that the value inside of the input tag is not incrementing but if I click the button with id "#down" the value goes to -1

```js
let down = document.getElementById('down');
let up = document.getElementById('up');
let input = document.getElementById('step');

down.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.value = input.textContent - 1;
});

up.addEventListener('click', function() {
  input.valuet = input.textContent + 1;
});
```

```html
<div class="stepper-conteiner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between py-4">
  <button class="stepper-container_button rounded-circle" id="down">-</button>
  <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="step" class="stepper-container__input text-center" readonly></input>
  <button class="stepper-container_button rounded-circle" id="up">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Typo (`input.valuet`)
2. You can set the value to any number using script so look at the max and min
3. value is a string. Field has a value, not a textContent

```js
let down = document.getElementById('down');
let up = document.getElementById('up');
let input = document.getElementById('step');
let stepValue = +input.step

down.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let val  = +input.value; // the unary plus casts to number
  if (val > input.min) input.value = val - stepValue;
});

up.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let val  = +input.value;
  if (val<input.max) input.value = val + stepValue;
});
```

```html
<div class="stepper-conteiner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between py-4">
  <button class="stepper-container_button rounded-circle" id="down">-</button>
  <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="step" class="stepper-container__input text-center" readonly></input>
  <button class="stepper-container_button rounded-circle" id="up">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- in the up event listener => input.valuet remove the "t"
2- change the textContent to value and parse them before making the calcul, if the value is undefined or NaN so 0 will be used.

Some browser do not suposed the NaN as false and in this case you need to check if NaN and take other number, depend on your need.

```
let down = document.getElementById('down');
let up = document.getElementById('up');
let input = document.getElementById('step');

down.addEventListener('click', function () {
  input.value = (parseInt(input.value) || 0) - 1;
});

up.addEventListener('click', function () {
  input.value = (parseInt(input.value) || 0) + 1;
});

<div class="stepper-conteiner d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between py-4">
      <button class="stepper-container_button rounded-circle" id="down">-</button>
      <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" step="1" id="step" class="stepper-container__input text-center" readonly></input>
      <button class="stepper-container_button rounded-circle" id="up">+</button>
    </div>
```